# How to remove an element from a dynamically allocated array of objects with operator -= without using std::vectors?

Tags: c++, class, object, dynamic-allocation

Overloading the operator -=:

```
RentACar& operator-=(const Automobile& av)
```

In RentACar i have a dynamically allocated array of Automobile *a

So lets say that if any `a` has the same `a.brand` with `av.brand` then that a should be removed and the allocated memory freed for one object.

I thought sth. like if it doesnt find an object with the same brand it return *this, but if it does, it allocates space for a new automobile array of size of a-1, assigns objects of, skips the one with the same brand, but i dont know how to write it.

I don't know how to write with vectors and push back, anyway, i study for an exam and we never used vectors for whatever reason so i can't use them on the exam so i must do this even if it is a stupid implementation!

Thanks!

Comment: That's operator overloading abuse 101. Use a member function, please, like `Find_and_remove` or something like that.

Comment: Its inefficient to delete an element from an array, consider a linked list.

Comment: If i knew sth. like that i would have!

Comment: @HAL: Depends on where you're deleting.

Comment: Ignoring the operator abuse, use `std::vector::erase()`.

Comment: @jrok Except that if I understand him correctly, the assignment requires using `operator -=`.  Not a very good course, IMHO: teaching memory management (a very advanced topic) before `std::vector` (a fairly elementary topic); teaching operator overload abuse; and who knows what else that's bad.

Comment: @thokra offcourse, but prepare for the worst and hope for the best :)

Comment: @HAL Have you actually measured this.  You generally want to avoid linked lists, because they are very, very inefficient.

Comment: @HAL: No, think carefully about your design and use containers that fit.

Comment: @JamesKanze No but isn't it better than deleting an element(or shifting the elements)in an array?

Comment: @thokra Yes, and for this case(with whatever little we know from the question), I felt a list fits better than an array.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, he can switch with the last element, then pop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to find the object you want to remove:
`std::find_if` is good for this, but if it is classwork, they
may expect you to write your own implementation of a linear
search.  Once you've found the entry, you `delete` the pointer,
and either set it to null (and ensure that all other logic works
correctly when there are null pointers in the array), or shift
all of the following entries down one.  (`std::copy` could be
used for the shift.)  Of course, if you shift, you'll also have
to keep track of where the valid entries in the array end.

There's not really any reason to create a new array when
removing objects.  Just keep track of the logical end of the
array.